# App won't run unless you update Google Play services

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, firebase, google-play-services

I'm fairly new to developing and have my Google Maps API working perfectly, only snag I have is that in my gradle dependencies I have to `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.+'` instead of play-services 10.0.1.

When I use 10.0.1 on my emulator (the android studio emulator, api25), I open my maps activity I just get

> com.android.tools.fd.runtime.BootstrapApplication won't run unless you update Google Play services.

I have all the needed packages installed and everything, not sure why, but no issues at all when I use "play-services:9.+".

However, trying to link my app into Firebase, obviously requires me to use 10.0.1. Is there anything I can do to fix both issues?

Answer (score 3):

Any device or emulator will need to have at minimum the version of Google Play Services that your app is compiled with. Standard practice is to prompt the user to upgrade if the version of Google Play Services on the device is lower than needed.

Here is the new way to prompt the user to upgrade Google Play Services. Call this `checkPlayServices()` method when your app is first launched:

```
public static final int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 999;
GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI;
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if(googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
            googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        }

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If the device has an older version of Google Play Services, the update prompt will be shown:

[image]

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate it!  I get the update prompt to show on application startup on the emulator, but when I update the dialog box closes and I still have the same issue when I go to my maps activity.  Sorry I'm totally new to development.  Is there a way to get the emulator to run on 10.0.1? When I go to SDK tools, it shows that i got version 38 installed for google play services and version 41 for the google repository.

Comment: For an emulator with the latest version of Google Play Services, you might want to try Genymotion.  Just realize that there is no issue in your code, it's strictly an issue with the version of Google Play Services on the emulator.  This should never be a problem on a real device, as you can just update Google Play Services.

Comment: Correct. Its strange that the others says it automatically prompt (but at least not in my test case using 10.0.1 version of Firebase and Play Services 2.0.12).